Filter by ObjectId with equals operator in $search pipeline stage does not work
I use Prisma ORM in a Next.js environment, and I want to search a database collection but restrict the search to the scope of data created by a specific user.
I used MongoDB Atlas Search with the $search operator, which includes a compound operator and a filter clause within it. The filter clause caused no data to be returned from the whole search.
Below is the whole pipeline setting.
{
    pipeline: [
        {
            $search: {
                index: 'full-text-index',
                compound: {
                    filter: [
                        {
                            equals: {
                                value: new ObjectId(userId),
                                path: 'user_id',
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                    should: [
                        {
                            autocomplete: {
                                path: 'sentence',
                                query: term,
                                tokenOrder: 'any',
                                fuzzy: {
                                    maxEdits: 2,
                                    prefixLength: 1,
                                    maxExpansions: 256,
                                },
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            text: {
                                query: term,
                                path: 'note',
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            text: {
                                query: term,
                                path: 'translation',
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                    minimumShouldMatch: 1,
                },
                sort: { score: { $meta: 'searchScore' } },
            },
        },

        { $limit: ENTRIES_PER_PAGE },
        {
            $addFields: {
                id: { $toString: '$_id' },
                sentencePlusPhoneticSymbols: '$sentence_plus_phonetic_symbols',
            },
        },
        {
            $project: {
                _id: 0,
                id: 1,
                sentencePlusPhoneticSymbols: 1,
                translation: 1,
                note: 1,
                score: { $meta: 'searchScore' },
            },
        },
    ],
}

I tried to post a topic on the MongoDB developer community, you can view more detail with this link, but I haven't received response yet. Does any body have a clue what I did wrong?

It's actually a Prisma bug.
https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/15013#issuecomment-1381397966
Change the filter clause to the following worked.
filter: [
    {
        equals: {
            value: { $oid: userId },
            path: 'user_id',
        },
    },
],

